# C++ overide global operator comma gives error

Tags: c++, operators, comma-operator

the second function gives error C2803 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy7kx46x%28VS.80%29.aspx : 'operator ,' must have at least one formal parameter of class type. any clue?

```
template<class T,class A = std::allocator<T>> 
class Sequence : public std::vector<T,A> {
 public:
    Sequence<T,A>& operator,(const T& a) {
        this->push_back(a);
        return *this;
    }
    Sequence<T,A>& operator,(const Sequence<T,A>& a) {
        for(Sequence<T,A>::size_type i=0 ; i<a.size() ; i++) {
            this->push_back(a.at(i));
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

//this works!
template<typename T> 
Sequence<T> operator,(const T& a, const T&b) {
    Sequence<T> seq;
    seq.push_back(a);
    seq.push_back(b);
    return seq;
}

//this gives error C2803!
Sequence<double> operator,(const double& a, const double& b) {
    Sequence<double> seq;
    seq.push_back(a);
    seq.push_back(b);
    return seq;
}
```

Comment: You can't overload operators for the built-in types. And your repeated attempts to overload op, are misguided - it's not a magic bullet.

Comment: @Neil, your comments are awsome. I like them xD

Comment: It's a magic bullet which always shoots you in the foot!

Comment: @neil: what happen if I overload operator using template, so the argument could be built-in types as the first function above? its compile and work, does it dangerous?

Comment: @uray: what happens is, `(1.0,0.0)` uses the built-in `operator,` for doubles, not the template you've defined. On my machine following a corrected version of your code, `typeid((1.0,0.0)).name()` is "d".

Comment: What you are doing is horribly evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change that to:

```
Sequence<double> operator,(const Sequence<double>& a, const double& b)
{
    Sequence<double> seq(a);
    seq.push_back(b);
    return seq;
}
```

or (based on [this article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)):

```
Sequence<double> operator,(Sequence<double> seq, const double& b)
{
    seq.push_back(b);
    return seq;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you can't overload operator if at least one of the parameters of it is not a custom made class or something not primitive like enum. You can't overload `+` for `int` types and similarly you can't overload `,` for `double` types.

Comment: The compile error is misguiding. An operator function can go well with both parameters being enumerations.